# Android: How to split a very long String with items that are multiple lines long?

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist, split

I have a very long string, which came from a file that my app downloads from the internet. Now after I've turned the file into a string, I split the string using String.split and then go through the file turning the things I've split into Strings (pieces), with the String "Description" usually containing multiple lines. After that I put those strings in a custom arraylist, then I use a custom adapter to display each item that I put in the arraylist, except it only displays the first line of Description. How can I make it so it displays all the lines in "Description?

How do I make it so that the read.line thinks of the "Description" pieces as one line, or is there some way to make it so that the line in "Description" are always combined?

Here's the content of the string that I'm trying to parse:

```
"","ZQ11ISF1","1","INSTRUCTIONAL SKILLS","MARKOVIC","","","","" "","TQS11QP2","1","COMPUTER PROGRAMMING 2","THORP","","","","" "","ZLF","1","FRIDAY LUNCH","MARKOVIC","","","","" "","PHS84","17","HEALTH & WELLNESS TERM 4 OF 8","REED","","","","" "","PQS11QPI","1","INDV. PHYS ED","MARKOVIC","","","","" "18342","SCS22","1","CHEMISTRY 2 OF 2","Mott","Chemistry HW for tomorrow","2014-06-03","Homework","

Hello chemistry students,



We did the acid base conductivity lab today in class.  There are 29 questions and 11 summary questions.  I stated at the beginning of class today that there would be no homework except for determining who your partner(s) will be for the PBA presentation.  I’ll stand by that.  In class tomorrow we will finish the questions.  I hope you’ve started to research/write your PBA paper.  Remember to write down the information (title, author, web address, webpage title, date of publication if possible, publisher and location if book)  of any source you use so that you can put it into you bibliography at the end.  Your textbook would be a wise choice as one of your sources.


Note:

The Bronsted-Lowry Theory (1932) of Acids and Bases (which we have been adopting in class so far) states:
Acids donate protons (H+)

Bases accept protons (H+)

The Arrhenius Theory (1887) of Acids and Bases (which this lab introduces on the back of the second page) states:

Acids produce protons (H+)

Bases produce hydroxide ions (OH-)

Historically, the Bronsted-Lowry Theory came second and it doesn’t contradict the Arrhenius Theory. It only broadens it because the Arrhenius Theory limits bases to chemicals with OH- ions.  Some chemicals, however, like NH3 (which don’t have OH- ions) do act like bases by neutralizing acids.   Neutralize means that an acid and a base combine to form a salt, sometimes water would need to be evaporated to extract the salt.

Neutrally,

Mr. Mott

" "","SXGPW","1","PBAT Science","","","","","" "","MXGRW","1","PBAT Algebra 2/Trig ","","","","","" "","EES84","4","ENGLISH 10 2 OF 2","GURALNICK","","","","" "18265","FSS84","8","SPANISH II 2 OF 2","RATCLIFFE","Tarea para 6/3","2014-06-03","Homework","

 1. The last page of your PBA review packets both readings.

ANSWER QUESTIONS IN COMPLETE SENTENCES.

" "18413","HGS44","10","GLOBAL STUDIES 10 2 OF 2","Anderson","Intro Paragraph and EDAC","2014-06-03","Homework","

 For homework tonight, please finish your introductory paragraph and any remaining EDAC sheets for your essay. Come to class tomorrow with a printed copy (in print, no phones!!!) of your intro and EDAC sheets finished for each of your body paragraphs.

Have a great night!

" "18330","MRS22","7","ALGEBRA 2 / TRIG 2 OF 2","KLEIN","HW #28","2014-06-03","Homework","

 A.  pg. 803 #24,25,28,30,31

B.  Check your answers here.

www.beaconschool.org/~sklein/Algebra2/a2hwtriglos.pdf

C.  Create the FIRST half of your Study Sheet for the Trig Test on Monday, 6/9/14. 

"
```

Edit: I've figured out the read.line actually starts the while loop again each time it reads a new line, but it remembers what variable it was on so it creates a whole new "Description" String each time it encounters a new line (and new lines are only in the "Description" part of the String) and that gets added to the custom arraylist. So I need to figure out how to make it so it doesn't think that description is split onto different lines.

Edit: I think using Scanner would do away with my problem, but if I use scanner in a while loop it doesn't continue where it left off every time it loops, and it doesn't close itself when its done with the file.

Things I've Tried:

- Make the string "Description" all one line (then the actual parser returns nothing)
- Add .trim() to the end (Does nothing)
- Removed the "check if "Type" was null", which added a number of ListView parts, which contained other lines of the String "Description"

Here is the code for the actual parser

```
Log.d("homework due today", Due_Today);


            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(Due_Today.getBytes());


            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));



            try {

                while ((Due_Today = reader.readLine()) != null) {   
            String[] part = Due_Today.split("\",\"", -1);
            int noOfItems = part.length;
            int counter=0;
            Description = counter<noOfItems ? part[counter] : "";
            counter++;
            Band = counter<noOfItems ? part[counter] : "";
            counter++;
            Number = counter<noOfItems ? part[counter] : "";
            counter++;
            Class = counter<noOfItems ? part[counter] : "";
            counter++;
            Teacher = counter<noOfItems ? part[counter] : "";
            counter++;
            Title = counter<noOfItems ? part[counter] : "";
            counter++;
            Date = counter<noOfItems ? part[counter] : "";
            counter++;
            Type = counter<noOfItems ? part[counter] : "";
            counter++;
            Data = counter<noOfItems ? part[counter] : "";
            counter++; 


            Description = Description.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
            Band = Band.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
            Number = Number.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
            Class = Class.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
            Teacher = Teacher.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
            Title = Title.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
            Date = Date.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
            Type = Type.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
            Data = Data.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");






            Log.d("Data", Data);
            Log.d("Band", Band);
            Log.d("Number", Number);
            Log.d("Class", Class);
            Log.d("Teacher", Teacher);
            Log.d("Title", Title);
            Log.d("Date", Date);
            Log.d("Type", Type);
            Log.d("Description", Description);



            due_today_list.add(new Due_Today_List(Data, Band, Number, Class, Teacher, Title, Date, Type, Description));
```

Code for custom adapter

```
private void populateListView() {
        ArrayAdapter<Due_Today_List> adapter = new Due_TodayAdapter();
        ListView list = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);




    }


    public class Due_TodayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Due_Today_List>  {
        public Due_TodayAdapter() {
            super(getActivity(), R.layout.item_view, due_today_list);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;




            if(convertView==null){
            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
             holder = new ViewHolder();



             holder.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_iconclass);



             holder.HomeworkDueText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_texthomeworkdue);

            holder.DescriptionText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_textdescription);

            holder.TeacherText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_textteacher);

            holder.TypeText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_texttype);

            convertView.setTag(holder);


            }

        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }



        Due_Today_List currenthomeworkdue = due_today_list.get(position);

            if(currenthomeworkdue.getType() != null && !currenthomeworkdue.getType().isEmpty()){






        Teacher = currenthomeworkdue.getTeacher().substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+currenthomeworkdue.getTeacher().substring(1).toLowerCase();

        Description = currenthomeworkdue.getDescription().substring(5); 



        if(currenthomeworkdue.Band.substring(0, Math.min(currenthomeworkdue.Band.length(), 1)).equals("S")){

        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.science);


        }


        if(currenthomeworkdue.Band.substring(0, Math.min(currenthomeworkdue.Band.length(), 1)).equals("M")){

            holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mathematics);


            }


        if(currenthomeworkdue.Band.substring(0, Math.min(currenthomeworkdue.Band.length(), 1)).equals("H")){

            holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.global_studies);


            }

        if(currenthomeworkdue.Band.substring(0, Math.min(currenthomeworkdue.Band.length(), 2)).equals("FS")){

            holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.spanish);


            }

        if(currenthomeworkdue.Band.substring(0, Math.min(currenthomeworkdue.Band.length(), 1)).equals("E")){

            holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.english);


            }

        holder.HomeworkDueText.setText(currenthomeworkdue.getTitle());

        holder.DescriptionText.setText(Description);


        holder.TeacherText.setText(Teacher);

        holder.TypeText.setText(currenthomeworkdue.getType());

        return convertView;

            } else {


                View empty = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.empty_item, parent, false);



       return empty;






        }

        }
```

Here is what the Log returns

```
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): "","ZQ11ISF1","1","INSTRUCTIONAL SKILLS","MARKOVIC","","","",""
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): "","TQS11QP2","1","COMPUTER PROGRAMMING 2","THORP","","","",""
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): "","ZLF","1","FRIDAY LUNCH","MARKOVIC","","","",""
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): "","PHS84","17","HEALTH & WELLNESS TERM 4 OF 8","REED","","","",""
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): "","PQS11QPI","1","INDV. PHYS ED","MARKOVIC","","","",""
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): "18342","SCS22","1","CHEMISTRY 2 OF 2","Mott","Chemistry HW for tomorrow","2014-06-03","Homework","
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127):  
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127):  
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): Hello chemistry students,
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): We did the acid base conductivity lab today in class.  There are 29 questions and 11 summary questions.  I stated at the beginning of class today that there would be no homework except for determining who your partner(s) will be for the PBA presentation.  I’ll stand by that.  In class tomorrow we will finish the questions.  I hope you’ve started to research/write your PBA paper.  Remember to write down the information (title, author, web address, webpage title, date of publication if possible, publisher and location if book)  of any source you use so that you can put it into you bibliography at the end.  Your textbook would be a wise choice as one of your sources.
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): Note:
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): The Bronsted-Lowry Theory (1932) of Acids and Bases (which we have been adopting in class so far) states:?  
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): Acids donate protons (H+)
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): Bases accept protons (H+)
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): The Arrhenius Theory (1887) of Acids and Bases (which this lab introduces on the back of the second page) states: 
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): Acids produce protons (H+)
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): Bases produce hydroxide ions (OH-)
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): Historically, the Bronsted-Lowry Theory came second and it doesn’t contradict the Arrhenius Theory. It only broadens it because the Arrhenius Theory limits bases to chemicals with OH- ions.  Some chemicals, however, like NH3 (which don’t have OH- ions) do act like bases by neutralizing acids.   Neutralize means that an acid and a base combine to form a salt, sometimes water would need to be evaporated to extract the salt. 
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127):  
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): Neutrally,
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): Mr. Mott
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127):  
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): "
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): "","SXGPW","1","PBAT Science","","","","",""
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): "","MXGRW","1","PBAT Algebra 2/Trig ","","","","",""
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): "","EES84","4","ENGLISH 10 2 OF 2","GURALNICK","","","",""
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): "18265","FSS84","8","SPANISH II 2 OF 2","RATCLIFFE","Tarea para 6/3","2014-06-03","Homework","
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127):  1. The last page of your PBA review packets both readings.
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127):  
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): ANSWER QUESTIONS IN COMPLETE SENTENCES.
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): "
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): "18413","HGS44","10","GLOBAL STUDIES 10 2 OF 2","Anderson","Intro Paragraph and EDAC","2014-06-03","Homework","
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127):  For homework tonight, please finish your introductory paragraph and any remaining EDAC sheets for your essay. Come to class tomorrow with a printed copy (in print, no phones!!!) of your intro and EDAC sheets finished for each of your body paragraphs.
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): Have a great night!
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): "
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): "18330","MRS22","7","ALGEBRA 2 / TRIG 2 OF 2","KLEIN","HW #28","2014-06-03","Homework","
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127):  A.  pg. 803 #24,25,28,30,31
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): B.  Check your answers here.
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): www.beaconschool.org/~sklein/Algebra2/a2hwtriglos.pdf
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): C.  Create the FIRST half of your Study Sheet for the Trig Test on Monday, 6/9/14. 
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127): "
07-21 21:33:14.704: D/homework due today(8127):     
07-21 21:33:14.714: D/Band(8127): ZQ11ISF1
07-21 21:33:14.714: D/Number(8127): 1
07-21 21:33:14.714: D/Class(8127): INSTRUCTIONAL SKILLS
07-21 21:33:14.714: D/Teacher(8127): MARKOVIC
07-21 21:33:14.714: D/Band(8127): TQS11QP2
07-21 21:33:14.714: D/Number(8127): 1
07-21 21:33:14.714: D/Class(8127): COMPUTER PROGRAMMING 2
07-21 21:33:14.714: D/Teacher(8127): THORP
07-21 21:33:14.714: D/Band(8127): ZLF
07-21 21:33:14.714: D/Number(8127): 1
07-21 21:33:14.714: D/Class(8127): FRIDAY LUNCH
07-21 21:33:14.714: D/Teacher(8127): MARKOVIC
07-21 21:33:14.714: D/Band(8127): PHS84
07-21 21:33:14.724: D/Number(8127): 17
07-21 21:33:14.724: D/Class(8127): HEALTH & WELLNESS TERM 4 OF 8
07-21 21:33:14.724: D/Teacher(8127): REED
07-21 21:33:14.724: D/Band(8127): PQS11QPI
07-21 21:33:14.724: D/Number(8127): 1
07-21 21:33:14.724: D/Class(8127): INDV. PHYS ED
07-21 21:33:14.724: D/Teacher(8127): MARKOVIC
07-21 21:33:14.724: D/Band(8127): SCS22
07-21 21:33:14.724: D/Number(8127): 1
07-21 21:33:14.724: D/Class(8127): CHEMISTRY 2 OF 2
07-21 21:33:14.734: D/Teacher(8127): Mott
07-21 21:33:14.734: D/Title(8127): Chemistry HW for tomorrow
07-21 21:33:14.734: D/Date(8127): 2014-06-03
07-21 21:33:14.734: D/Type(8127): Homework
07-21 21:33:14.734: D/Description(8127): 18342
07-21 21:33:14.734: D/Description(8127):  
07-21 21:33:14.744: D/Description(8127):  
07-21 21:33:14.754: D/Description(8127): Hello chemistry students,
07-21 21:33:14.754: D/Description(8127): We did the acid base conductivity lab today in class.  There are 29 questions and 11 summary questions.  I stated at the beginning of class today that there would be no homework except for determining who your partner(s) will be for the PBA presentation.  I’ll stand by that.  In class tomorrow we will finish the questions.  I hope you’ve started to research/write your PBA paper.  Remember to write down the information (title, author, web address, webpage title, date of publication if possible, publisher and location if book)  of any source you use so that you can put it into you bibliography at the end.  Your textbook would be a wise choice as one of your sources.
07-21 21:33:14.764: D/Description(8127): Note:
07-21 21:33:14.774: D/Description(8127): The Bronsted-Lowry Theory (1932) of Acids and Bases (which we have been adopting in class so far) states:?  
07-21 21:33:14.774: D/Description(8127): Acids donate protons (H+)
07-21 21:33:14.784: D/Description(8127): Bases accept protons (H+)
07-21 21:33:14.784: D/Description(8127): The Arrhenius Theory (1887) of Acids and Bases (which this lab introduces on the back of the second page) states: 
07-21 21:33:14.794: D/Description(8127): Acids produce protons (H+)
07-21 21:33:14.804: D/Description(8127): Bases produce hydroxide ions (OH-)
07-21 21:33:14.804: D/Description(8127): Historically, the Bronsted-Lowry Theory came second and it doesn’t contradict the Arrhenius Theory. It only broadens it because the Arrhenius Theory limits bases to chemicals with OH- ions.  Some chemicals, however, like NH3 (which don’t have OH- ions) do act like bases by neutralizing acids.   Neutralize means that an acid and a base combine to form a salt, sometimes water would need to be evaporated to extract the salt. 
07-21 21:33:14.804: D/Description(8127):  
07-21 21:33:14.814: D/Description(8127): Neutrally,
07-21 21:33:14.814: D/Description(8127): Mr. Mott
07-21 21:33:14.824: D/Description(8127):  
07-21 21:33:14.824: D/Band(8127): SXGPW
07-21 21:33:14.824: D/Number(8127): 1
07-21 21:33:14.824: D/Class(8127): PBAT Science
07-21 21:33:14.824: D/Band(8127): MXGRW
07-21 21:33:14.824: D/Number(8127): 1
07-21 21:33:14.824: D/Class(8127): PBAT Algebra 2/Trig 
07-21 21:33:14.824: D/Band(8127): EES84
07-21 21:33:14.824: D/Number(8127): 4
07-21 21:33:14.824: D/Class(8127): ENGLISH 10 2 OF 2
07-21 21:33:14.824: D/Teacher(8127): GURALNICK
07-21 21:33:14.824: D/Band(8127): FSS84
07-21 21:33:14.824: D/Number(8127): 8
07-21 21:33:14.824: D/Class(8127): SPANISH II 2 OF 2
07-21 21:33:14.824: D/Teacher(8127): RATCLIFFE
07-21 21:33:14.824: D/Title(8127): Tarea para 6/3
07-21 21:33:14.824: D/Date(8127): 2014-06-03
07-21 21:33:14.824: D/Type(8127): Homework
07-21 21:33:14.824: D/Description(8127): 18265
07-21 21:33:14.834: D/Description(8127):  1. The last page of your PBA review packets both readings.
07-21 21:33:14.834: D/Description(8127):  
07-21 21:33:14.834: D/Description(8127): ANSWER QUESTIONS IN COMPLETE SENTENCES.
07-21 21:33:14.844: D/Band(8127): HGS44
07-21 21:33:14.844: D/Number(8127): 10
07-21 21:33:14.844: D/Class(8127): GLOBAL STUDIES 10 2 OF 2
07-21 21:33:14.844: D/Teacher(8127): Anderson
07-21 21:33:14.844: D/Title(8127): Intro Paragraph and EDAC
07-21 21:33:14.844: D/Date(8127): 2014-06-03
07-21 21:33:14.844: D/Type(8127): Homework
07-21 21:33:14.844: D/Description(8127): 18413
07-21 21:33:14.844: D/Description(8127):  For homework tonight, please finish your introductory paragraph and any remaining EDAC sheets for your essay. Come to class tomorrow with a printed copy (in print, no phones!!!) of your intro and EDAC sheets finished for each of your body paragraphs.
07-21 21:33:14.844: D/Description(8127): Have a great night!
07-21 21:33:14.854: D/Band(8127): MRS22
07-21 21:33:14.854: D/Number(8127): 7
07-21 21:33:14.854: D/Class(8127): ALGEBRA 2 / TRIG 2 OF 2
07-21 21:33:14.854: D/Teacher(8127): KLEIN
07-21 21:33:14.854: D/Title(8127): HW #28
07-21 21:33:14.854: D/Date(8127): 2014-06-03
07-21 21:33:14.854: D/Type(8127): Homework
07-21 21:33:14.854: D/Description(8127): 18330
07-21 21:33:14.854: D/Description(8127):  A.  pg. 803 #24,25,28,30,31
07-21 21:33:14.854: D/Description(8127): B.  Check your answers here.
07-21 21:33:14.854: D/Description(8127): www.beaconschool.org/~sklein/Algebra2/a2hwtriglos.pdf
07-21 21:33:14.864: D/Description(8127): C.  Create the FIRST half of your Study Sheet for the Trig Test on Monday, 6/9/14. 
07-21 21:33:14.864: D/Description(8127):
```

Edit:
So I've resorted to trying to add a while loop inside the parser while loop which looks to gather up all the lines of "Description" and add them all to one string. I have not had a lot of luck with it, since it never seems to do what I want it to do. It skips all the first part of the file, which is what it should do, and then it gets the "Description" part together, but after that everything goes crazy and it adds all this extra stuff to the StringBuilder. Anyway here is the new parser code and its output in the log.

```
StringBuilder DescriptionAll = new StringBuilder();

            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(Due_Today.getBytes());


            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));



            try {

                while ((Due_Today = reader.readLine()) != null) {   
            String[] part = Due_Today.split("\",\"", -1);
            int noOfItems = part.length;
            int counter=0;


            DescriptionCheck = counter<noOfItems ? part[counter] : "";counter++;

            if (!Due_Today.contains("\",\"") && DescriptionCheck != null && !DescriptionCheck.isEmpty() ){

                while ((Due_Today = reader.readLine()) != null & !DescriptionCheck.contains("\",\"")) {



                    Log.d("DescriptionCheck", DescriptionCheck );

                    String[] parter = Due_Today.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"), -1);



                Description = parter[0];

                DescriptionAll.append((System.getProperty("line.separator") + Description));

                Log.d("descriptioncheck", Description );

                if (Description.contains("\",\"")) {


                    Log.d("BROKEN?", "YES" );

                    break;


                }

            }
            }

            Band = counter<noOfItems ? part[counter] : "";
            counter++;
            Number = counter<noOfItems ? part[counter] : "";
            counter++;
            Class = counter<noOfItems ? part[counter] : "";
            counter++;
            Teacher = counter<noOfItems ? part[counter] : "";
            counter++;
            Title = counter<noOfItems ? part[counter] : "";
            counter++;
            Date = counter<noOfItems ? part[counter] : "";
            counter++;
            Type = counter<noOfItems ? part[counter] : "";
            counter++;
            Data = counter<noOfItems ? part[counter] : "";
            counter++; 






            Band = Band.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
            Number = Number.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
            Class = Class.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
            Teacher = Teacher.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
            Title = Title.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
            Date = Date.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
            Type = Type.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
            Data = Data.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");






        Description =   DescriptionAll.toString();

        Description = Description.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");

            Log.d("Data", Data);
            Log.d("Band", Band);
            Log.d("Number", Number);
            Log.d("Class", Class);
            Log.d("Teacher", Teacher);
            Log.d("Title", Title);
            Log.d("Date", Date);
            Log.d("Type", Type);
            Log.d("Description", Description);
            Log.d("DescriptionAll", Description);




            due_today_list.add(new Due_Today_List(Data, Band, Number, Class, Teacher, Title, Date, Type, Description));
```

And [here](http://pastebin.com/M8ZT07ii) is what the log looks like now, pure craziness: http://pastebin.com/M8ZT07ii

Edit:

Here's a screenshot of what the app looks like when everything is sorted perfectly except "Description" (Where only the first line of Description for each one shows up), this uses the first code I tried (without the new while loop"

[image]

And here you can see that it only shows the first line of "Description

[image]

Here's what the app looks like when I use the new code with the while loop

[image]

Here's what the "Description" output is for the new code with the while loop, as you can see as a result of the while loop I remove the first line of "Description", which is ok because it's just a placeholder

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: I added it, even though I don't think that's what the problem is, but whatever helps. I could definitely be wrong about that though.

Comment: Looks like all the description is fine, it is being output in the log. Maybe your "TextView" is only one line tall? So the rest gets cut-off? Maybe is simply a display issue?

Comment: I tested it before with a very long string of words, and it didn't get cut off. So it shouldn't be a display issue.

Comment: @I'm_With_Stupid after reading all ur decription m bit confused ..can u expain inmore details in chat i would like to answer this question today

Comment: @adcom thanks for wanting to help. Basically I am trying to figure out a way to separate each piece of the string above by the delimiter [","], and convert that to a string. My parser will loop through the file, and convert something to a string based on the pattern of the items in the string. But when my parser encounters an item which has multiple lines, like "Description" does, it devotes a string to each line, it doesn't turn all the lines into one string. So I need to figure out how to make it so all the lines in Description are one string.

Comment: So far I have gotten it working well enough so that it separates all the items less than one line to be added to the right spot in the array list, but only the first line of the "Description" item is put in the correct spot in the array list,  since my parser splits up "Description" on each new line in it.

Comment: is ur string separated by , or / ? bit confusing

Comment: it's separated by quote comma quote, but android needs to use /" inorder to deal with quotes. so it's ","

Comment: @I'm_With_Stupid ohh ok , actually i m trying to paste ur content in file and trying to read it instead of making ur content a string ....and seperating ur 9 fields so bacially i can see ur facing issue while sepearting desvcition from these 9 filds

Comment: One thing is that each group of 9 fields need to be added to an array list as one line of the list, so that is why I was using strings before.

Comment: @adcom I can give you the files for the custom array list if you want them

Comment: Oh,  I see what you meant by changing the input to a file

Comment: @I'm_With_Stupid can u plz tell me what r the field in ur string whih is always present and never empty...i think date isnt it??

Comment: @adcom Band, Number, Class, Teacher are always present. And the other ones sometimes aren't present

Comment: @I'm_With_Stupid what about date?? sorry cannot come on chat internet is too slow

Comment: @adcom Date is sometimes not present, only those are, why do you need date?

Comment: actually i m unable to understand when these 9 fields get ended : i hv made a list sepearting the above content but i m unable to understand orally that how these set of 9 is present in ur content ..i m at half stage of coding

Comment: @adcom So it now seems like there is only 8 fields, no data field. Additionally the 8 fields end when their have been 8 fields, and a new group of 8 fields is created

Comment: @adcom also if 9 fields is working for you  now, then use 9 fields because it worked for me when I used my code.

Comment: "$#$

ZQ11ISF1

$#$

1

$#$

INSTRUCTIONAL SKILLS

$#$

MARKOVIC

$#$

-

$#$

-

$#$

-

$#$

" "

$#$

TQS11QP2

$#$

1

$#$

COMPUTER PROGRAMMING 2

$#$

THORP

$#$

-

$#$

-
$#$

-

$#$

" "

$#$

ZLF

$#$

1

$#$

FRIDAY LUNCH

$#$

MARKOVIC

$#$

$#$

$#$

$#$

" "

$#$

PHS84

$#$


17

$#$

HEALTH & WELLNESS TERM 4 OF 8

$#$

REED

$#$

$#$

$#$

$#$

" "

$#$


PQS11QPI

$#$

1

$#$

INDV. PHYS ED

$#$

MARKOVIC

$#$

$#$

$#$

$#$

" "

18342

$#$

SCS22

$#$

1

$#$

CHEMISTRY 2 OF 2

$#$

Mott

$#$

$#$
2014-06-03

Comment: this is one set i fell from above content is my sepeartion right??? how does this one set form 9 fields?

Comment: Well the first 8 variables in that is your first group of8 fields, and the next 8 variables in that will be your next group of 8 fields and so on until you run out of fields

Comment: no actually descition is of multiple lines i wanna see hoz does it extactly look like...

Comment: @adcom (Band, Number, Class, Teacher, Title, Date, Type, Description) is the format for the array list, as well as the order of the 8 fields. Also you can see the correct output in the log cat above. Does that answer your question ?

Comment: @I'm_With_Stupid actually no...i want to know polish out format, it would be great if u post clearly 8 or 9 set ....in ur logcat from ur content so that  i can view clearly the input and output actually my output code doent seems to be polished...i wish i would chat i woudl hv explained in details

Comment: @adcom the input will always be a repeating "," separated list of the 8 variables Band, Number, Class, Teacher, Title, Date, Type, Description. These variables could contain any variable at any given time. The output is the 8 variables that follow each other in the input string, and these 8 variables that are grouped together are added to an arraylist. Example output could be: FSS84 07-21 21:33:14.824: D/Number(8127): 8 07-21 21:33:14.824: D/Class(8127): SPANISH II 2 OF 2 07-21 21:33:14.824: D/Teacher(8127): RATCLIFFE 07-21 21:33:14.824: D/Title(8127): Tarea para 6/3 07-21 21:33:14.824: D/Date

Comment: Example output could be for one group: FSS84, 8, SPANISH II 2 OF 2, RATCLIFFE, Tarea para 6/3, 2014-06-03, Homework,  1. The last page of your PBA review packets both readings. ANSWER QUESTIONS IN COMPLETE SENTENCES.

Comment: @I'm_With_Stupid can u come on chat plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem comes from the fact that you are using `readLine` to read your file. By using this function the buffer is read until a line feed "\n" or carriage return "\r" is found. However, What you want is to split the string each time the occurrence ',' is found.

Try to use `read` instead to read through `Due_Today`. This is only a pseudo-code:

```
int value   = 0;
int counter = 0;
String str  = "";
StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();

// Read until the end of the file
while((value = reader.read()) != -1)
{
    // Convert int to a character
    char c = (char)value;
    strb.append(c);

    // If the separator is found
    if (c == ','){

        str = strb.toString().replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
        switch (counter) {

            /* Do things according to the value of counter:
            Read description, data, title.. according to the data structure of what you are trying to parse 

            Example:
            case 1:  Description = str;
            break;
            case 2:  Band = str;
            break;
            */

        }

        // Prepare to read a new string and initialize the string builder
        strb.setLength(0);
        counter ++;
    }
}
```

I do know exactly what is the data structure of the file you are parsing but you may have some problems if you must read more than one object in one file. I noticed that the "description" can contains some comma which will be seen as a separator. Therefore you can either read only one object and say "Once I start reading the description, read the file until the end no matter if there are some commas" or change the separator by a character that is not used in the content of your strings.

Hope this helps

**EDIT**

1) What about something like this to search for your separator? It might not be the perfect method but at least it is fast as it does not search for the entire separator pattern at each character.

```
while((value = reader.read()) != -1)
{
     // Convert int to a character
     char c = (char)value;


      // Searching for the separator
      if (c == ','){
           if (state == 1) {
                state = 2;
           } else {
                state = 0;
                strb.append(c);
            }
       }
       else if (c == '"'){
            if (state == 2){
                 // The separator if found, read the string
                 processElement(strb, counter); 

                  // Prepare to read a new string
                  state = 0;
                  counter ++;

             } else {
                  state = 1;
                  strb.append(c);
             }
       } else {
             strb.append(c);
       }
}

// Process the last element
processElement(strb, counter);


public void processElement(StringBuilder strb, int counter){
    String str = strb.toString().replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
    System.out.println("String to process= " + str);

    /*
         Do something with it here..

    switch (counter) {
        case 1:  Description = str;
        break;

        case 2:  Band = str;
        break;

        ...
    }
    */

    // Initialize the string builder
    strb.setLength(0);
}
```

2) If you are willing to read to file until the end, you can do it that way:

```
while((value = reader.read()) != -1)
{
     // Convert int to a character
     char c = (char)value;
     strb.append(c);
}
String str = strb.toString();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work because I'm not splitting on just comma, I'm splitting on quote comma quote (","), since this is three characters it won't work. Secondly .read() returns an integer, which I would rather not use. But your definitely on the right track, I've been trying to find something that does read it all instead of line by line but I can't. But thank you for the answer.

Comment: This does separate all of them, but for some reason it stops right before the last description, the one which begins with: A.  pg. 803 #24,25,28,30,31

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to process the last element. The post has been edited ;)

Comment: one more thing, would their be a way to repeat this method 8 times, but each time "str" is set to a different variable?

Comment: You can pass another variable to the function to specify to which variable you want to set the String. I have put an switch case example in my post.

Comment: This is too much material to read. So let me understand, you have a file which you parsed as a string and then you want to parse that string into individual smaller strings based on certain tags(like a xml file)?

Comment: @SeahawksRdaBest Exactly, but the above code seems to work with a few changes. But I'm having trouble finding a way to get 8 different strings during each loop.

Comment: Better Question, what are the delimiters for each "smaller" string you are trying to use?

Comment: the delimiter is quote comma quote aka ","

Comment: so i figured out how to use this code to get it to work, but it had to be heavily modified.

Answer (score 1):

So I think you are complicating the parsing of the String into smaller segments way more then it needs to be.

### Here is what I would do:

#### A. I would use the [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path)) Class specifically the readAllBytes method to read the contents of my entire file into a byte array.

Like so

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;

Path path = Paths.get("path/to/file");
byte[] myArray = Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

#### B. After reading in the file I would convert the byte[] into a String.

Like so

```
String myString = new String(myArray);
```

#### C. Finally I would use String function Split.

```
String[] myStringArray = myString.spilt(",");
```

myStringArray will hold all your relevant "substrings", to do with as you please.